# Is there some kind of guard you can wear on bottom front teeth to protect gums?

Tags: dentistry, gums, mouth-guard

Imagine foods that require you to really sink your teeth into and can't be broken into small chunks like a tough big piece of barbecue meat.

There must be some kind of mouth guard that has teeth on it that you can wear over front bottom teeth to protect the gums against the physical pressing. Has anyone/any company attempted to make something like this?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, do you have some sort of gum disease? Why do you need to protect your gums against normal eating?

Comment: I would suggest mentioning why you want this as there may be a better solution. I find it is better to explain my issue, then include what I think is the best solution. There may be someone who can suggest something that is much better.

Comment: You can always edit your own posts. Please do not create a second account to edit your own posts.